# PHP not executing properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following code doesn't work and the `echo` string is a null string when the php page is called.

However, when I remove the part where I check whether username already exists, the code works as expected.

Why is this happening?

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=tipcc;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', 'plsdonthack');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// This Part Is Causing Some Problem

$flag=0;
$temp = $_GET[username];
$stmt2 = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE USERNAME=:username2)");
$stmt2->bindParam (':username2',$temp,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt2->execute ();

// Till Here.

if ($stmt2->rowCount () > 0 )
{
    $flag=1;
}

if ($flag == 0)
{
 // This Part Works Fine

    $stmt=$db->prepare ("INSERT INTO userinfo (NAME,IDNO,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
    VALUES
    (:name,:idno,:username,:password)");

    $stmt->bindParam (':name',$_GET[name], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':idno',$_GET[idno], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':username',$_GET[username], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':password',$_GET[password], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute () == 1 )
        {
            echo "Registered Sucessfully...!! Goto Contests and Code..!";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not Registered Due To Some Internal Error....Contact Rohith R";
        }
  // Till Here
}

else
{
    echo "Username Already Exists....Choose Another One";
}



?>
```

Comment: `$temp = $_GET[username];` you forgot to quote the key: `$temp = $_GET['username'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in your SQL code

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE USERNAME=:username2)
```

Remove closing bracket at the end of statement.

Your code throws an exception but you do not see it because of switched off parameter `display_error` in PHP config.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in a try/catch block:

```
try{

// your queries here

}catch(PDOException $Exception){
    echo $Exception->getMessage();
}
```

You can throw another exception after you see or log it.